Meaning of $d(x_m,x_n)\to 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$
Consider the next lemma:
 Lemma. A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on a metric space $(X,d)$ is a Cauchy sequences, if and only if, $d(x_m,x_n)\to 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
I don't understand the formal meaning of the expression "$d(x_m,x_n)\to 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$". Intuitively, it means that, when $m$ and $n$ are large, the distance from $x_m$ to $x_n$ is zero, i.e.
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} d(x_m,x_n)=0.\hspace{1 in} (1)
$$
I know what it means for a sequence to converge, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(x_m,x_n)$ is not a sequence as far as I understand, so the expression (1) has no meaning. What's the sequence $d(x_m,x_n)$ corresponds? What's the formal definition of "$d(x_m,x_n)\to 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$"?

Another way to put it might be to say $d(x_m, x_n) \to 0$ as $(m, n) \to (\infty, \infty)$, where the latter part is with respect to the filter on $\mathbb{N}^2$ generated by sets $[N, \infty) \times [N, \infty)$ (and the former part is with respect to the standard neighborhood filter of 0 on $\mathbb{R}$).  Of course, unpacking that requires some familiarity with the notion of filter; but in my opinion, the language of filters is probably the best way to unify the numerous versions of limit that are floating around in the study of real analysis.

@DanielSchepler, do you know a book where I can learn more from that you are talking about?

Would you please give us the name of the book you are reading to let us have more context? @RataMágica

I don't know of a book for reference, but the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(set_theory) could be a good place to start, at least as far as learning the definitions.  For the relation to limits which isn't on that page as far as I can see: if $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on $X$, $\mathcal{G}$ is a filter on $Y$, and $f : X\to Y$ a function, then define $f(x)\to\mathcal{G}$ as $x\to\mathcal{F}$ to mean: for every $S\in\mathcal{G}$, we have $f^{-1}(S)\in\mathcal{F}$.

In this case, $X = \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$; $\mathcal{F} = { S\subseteq\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mid \exists N\in \mathbb{N}, [N,\infty)\times [N,\infty)\subseteq S}$; $Y = \mathbb{R}$; $\mathcal{G} = { S\subseteq\mathbb{R} \mid \exists \varepsilon>0, (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\subseteq S }$; and $f : (m, n) \mapsto d(x_m, x_n)$.

@DanielSchepler, in your first previous answer, are $X$ and $Y$ just sets or topological spaces?

You only need $X$ and $Y$ to be sets with some filter on each.  Where topology would come in would be if you want to set one or both filters to be a neighborhood filter at some point.  (Or as another way of putting it, the filters you use will often be inspired by some topology, and studying limits of filters like this could be considered a generalization of sorts of the study of topological spaces.)
